# Setting up and understanding ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, datagridview

first of all:
I´m a student that is still learning about programming.
The problem is that when I right click in a row insde the dataGridView, the RightClickDataView.Items.Add("Abgegeben"); appears as many times as I click. How can I change this?

```
    private void dataGridViewBestellungen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var hti = dataGridViewBestellungen.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            dataGridViewBestellungen.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            RightClickDataView.Items.Add("Abgegeben");
            RightClickDataView.Show(Cursor.Position);
            var xy = dataGridViewBestellungen.SelectedRows;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in xy)
            {
                //take the id in the datagridview
            }
            RightClickDataView.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(rightclickmenu_ItemClicked);
            // close if mouse goes away from window
        }
    }

    private void rightclickmenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
        dataGridViewBestellungen.ClearSelection();
        if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Zurück")
        {
            //change the state to erledigt
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `RightClickDataView.Items.Add("Abgegeben");` from your `dataGridViewBestellungen_MouseDown` and place this line on your constructor for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i take out that line from the dataGridViewBestellungen_MouseDown, will it work?

Comment: It should. You just need to make sure you place this line after the object RightClickDataView is initialized.

Comment: Is not working, now is not appearing the first time i clicked, but the second time that I click appears 2 times. and the third time 3 times, and so on.

Comment: Can you update your code so people can see what looks like know?